# summarize percent calculation invalid 'type' error

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following code that was working but now it is throwing an error. I think a package may have updated and broke it.

```
scorecard_data %>% 
  select (STABBR, HBCU, MENONLY, WOMENONLY) %>%
  filter (str_detect(STABBR, "OH|PA|WV|KY|IN|MI")) %>%
  group_by (STABBR) %>% 
  summarize (prcntHBCU = (sum(HBCU, na.rm = TRUE)/length(HBCU[!is.na(HBCU)])*100),
             prcntMEN = (sum(MENONLY, na.rm = TRUE)/length(MENONLY[!is.na(MENONLY)])*100),
             prcntWOMEN = (sum(WOMENONLY, na.rm = TRUE)/length(WOMENONLY[!is.na(WOMENONLY)])*100)) %>%
  gather(key = 'Type.prcnt', value = 'Prcnt', prcntHBCU:prcntWOMEN) %>% 
  ggplot (aes (x = STABBR, y = Prcnt, fill = Type.prcnt)) +
  geom_col(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  ggtitle ("% of HBCUs, Men Only, and Women Only Institutions - by OH and Neighboring States") +
  xlab ("State") +
  ylab ("Percent of Institutions")
```

and here is the error R Studio is giving when I run it...

```
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `prcntHBCU`.
x invalid 'type' (character) of argument
i Input `prcntHBCU` is `(sum(HBCU, na.rm = TRUE)/length(HBCU[!is.na(HBCU)]) * 100)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: STABBR = "IN".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> rlang::last_error()
<error/dplyr_error>
Problem with `summarise()` input `prcntHBCU`.
x invalid 'type' (character) of argument
i Input `prcntHBCU` is `(sum(HBCU, na.rm = TRUE)/length(HBCU[!is.na(HBCU)]) * 100)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: STABBR = "IN".
Backtrace:
  1. dplyr::select(., STABBR, HBCU, MENONLY, WOMENONLY)
  1. dplyr::filter(., str_detect(STABBR, "OH|PA|WV|KY|IN|MI"))
  1. dplyr::group_by(., STABBR)
  2. dplyr::summarize(...)
 14. dplyr:::h(simpleError(msg, call))
```

Can anyone help debug this and tell me why it isn't working?

Comment: Hi! It would be good for you to share more of a minimum working example; because I do not have your `scorecard_data` data set, I can't definitively find an answer. But your error indicates you are trying to `sum` a character vector, which isn't allowed because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: specifically, check the `HBCU` column since the issue is with input `prcntHBCU`. Depending on how you are creating the dataframe `scorecard_data`, the column type may change when running with new/more data. For example, if you are reading it in from a file and some value in the file can't be interpreted as a number/boolean, the read function will usually leave it as a character.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @gregmacfarlane and @Calumn_You the cause is likely applying `sum` to a character vector.

One easy was to check the type of your variables is `summary(scorecard_data)`. Numeric variables will give min, max, median. Character variables will just say that the variable type is character. Factor variables will give a tally of the different counts.

You can convert characters to numeric with `as.numeric` assuming the character string is a number. If the variable is a factor, it is often best to first convert to character and then to numeric with `as.numeric` and `as.character`.

So you are probably looking for a solution like:

```r
scorecard_data %>%
  mutate(STABBR = as.numeric(STABBR), # if STABBR is of type character
         HBCU = as.numeric(as.character(HBCU)), # if HBCU is of type factor
         MENONLY = as.numeric(MENONLY),
         WOMENONLY = as.numeric(WOMENONLY)) %>%
#  the rest of your code follows here
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this was for an exam and I was in a hurry to get it finished. I did figure out right after I posted, it was a character vector! Don't remember why I checked, but I did. Oops.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, you all are great!

Comment: I didn't realize when it said "invalid type (character) of argument, what it was trying to tell me. Ha. Seems obvious now. I'm very new to this. Appreciate it!